# Realm Studio 3.8.2 fails to start on MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos, react-native, realm, macos-catalina, realm-studio

I have this issue on macOS Catalina
Realm Studio: 3.8.2
MacOS: 10.15.1
how can i fix that ? Thanks !
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General you will find your app blocked click on allow anway .